# How can I access a static variable from a static function?

Tags: c++

I have these data members static because Array will be an abstract class that will have have multiple classes that will inherit it. I want to be able to load data from a text file into my primaryCollections array.

**Keep getting an error when I try to compile my code:**

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: Array.o: warning: relocation against `_ZN5Array17primaryCollectionE' in read-only section `.text'
> /usr/bin/ld: Array.o: in function `Array::loadData(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
> Array.cc:(.text+0x240): undefined reference to `Array::primaryCollection'
> /usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [Makefile:6: p1] Error 1
> ```

#### `Array.cc`:

```
//loads data from text file into a list of record objects
void Array::loadData(string f){

  int year, employed, graduates;
  string province, degree, gender;

  ifstream file(f, ios::in);

  if (!file) {
    cout << "Error: could not open file" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  while ( file >> year >> province >> degree >> gender>> employed>> graduates ) {

    Record *record = new Record(year,province,degree,gender,employed,graduates);
    primaryCollection.push_back(record);

  }

  
}
```

#### `Array.h`:

```
class Array {

  
  public:

    static void loadData(string);

    
  private:
    string name;
    static vector<Record*> primaryCollection;

  

};
```

Comment: You've *declared* `primaryCollection`, but you haven't *defined* it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

With C++17 you can use the inline modifier:

`static inline vector<Record*> primaryCollection;`

This will work as expected.

If you are interested in details see:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline